# How do I deserialize XML into list<class>

Tags: c#, xml

**Given the following HTTP POST response (the request works):**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">schema</schema>xml</DataSet>
```

**And this XSD (XML Schema Definition, part):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
      <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
          <xs:complexType>
             <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="MTM">
                   <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="MTMDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name=......
```

....
More "column" elements follor after the `MTMDate` element.

**My code to try and deserialize data returned in XML:**

```
[XmlRoot("MTM")]
public class MTM
{
    [XmlElement("MTM")]
    public List<MTMItem> MTMData { get; set; }
}

public class MTMItem
{
    [XmlElement("MTMDate")]
    public DateTime MTMDate { get; set; }
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MTM));
MTM mtmData = (MTM)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream());
```

When running, on the line `MTM mtmData = ..` I get the following error:

`There is an error in XML document (2,2)`
`IvalidOperationException: <DataSet xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'> was not expected`

I presume I am getting the `[XmlRoot("MTM")]` part wrong and not following the `XSD Schema` correctly in order to deserialise into a `List<MTM>`?

**EDIT:**

`data` gets populated with `byte[]` data, is that my xml data that I then need to deserialize to a dataset?

```
  using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
      stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  }
```

Comment: Just want to confirm you know: that 'XML' that you have posted looks like an XSD (XML Schema Definition), not the actual "content" XML. That is, it is a definition for a format for XML, not the actual data that has been serialized to XML. Are you really trying to deserialize *that*? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)

Comment: hi @Jonathan, I am very new to xml and using a web service. As I understand, I need to use the XSD to deserialize the XML that is in the XSD format then?  I just want to get the XML data into a List<class>

Comment: That's what I suspected. Yes, you use the XSD (above) to create a structure (class) for the XML. Microsoft has an XSD tool to help generate classes (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-def-tool-gen). And then you could deserialize the provided XML to your class.

Comment: hi @Jonathan, I have the schema, thus it is fairly easy to generate the class manually.. as in the question above?  I think my problem lies rather in the deserializing step, or linking the XSD and class in the deserializing step? or what am I missing?

Comment: As @Tom W says below, you may be able to add a 'service reference' in Visual Studio. During the creation of the service reference, you would point to the service that you want to consume, and Visual Studio will actually build the proxy classes for reading, deserializing, etc. your service.

Comment: I'm not getting much right with @Tom W's suggestion, VS 2019 looks different too in the steps he outlines on that link. Doing it manually (with the xsd class generator) is preferred..

Comment: I suspect the difficulty you're having relates to the schema describing the objects **inside the dataset**, where a client built to consume this webservice would know that it needs to unpack the DataSet object and then interpret the results. The schema you're generating classes from doesn't say anthing about the DataSet class because it assumes that an old-style asp.net XML Web Service client already knows that.

Answer (score 1):

The XML content you've provided represents a .net object designed for representing database responses called a **DataSet**. You could write your own deserialization classes to pull just the data you want, but you are probably better off using the built-in behaviour in the .net framework [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/consuming-a-dataset-from-an-xml-web-service)

The part that is relevant is the section titled **Create an XML Web service client.** as the service already exists:

`If you want to have Visual Studio generate the Web service proxy class for you, simply create the client project, and, in the Solution Explorer window, right-click the project, and then select Add > Service Reference. In the Add Service Reference dialog box, select Advanced, and then select Add Web Reference. Select the Web service from the list of available Web services (this may require supplying the address of the Web service endpoint if the Web service isn't available within the current solution or on the current computer). If you create the XML Web service proxy yourself (as described in the previous step), you can import it into your client code and consume the XML Web service methods`

Comment: Could you give an example using the information in the question to show how I would build the deserialization myself?

Comment: I'm not getting much right with your suggestion, VS 2019 looks different too in the steps you outline above. Doing it manually (with the xsd class generator) is preferred.

Comment: That's a fair point and this framework is pretty old - I haven't tried it in VS2019. This was meant as a "frame challenge" to say that there is already a method designed to deal with this scenario that is different to your proposed solution. See comment on the original question...

Answer (score 1):

Basing another answer on the assumption that we **don't** want to generate a web service client:

I suspect the difficulty you're having relates to the schema describing the objects inside the dataset, where a client built to consume this webservice would know that it needs to unpack the DataSet object and then interpret the results. The schema you're generating classes from doesn't say anything about the DataSet class because it assumes that an old-style asp.net XML Web Service client already knows that.

So I'd think that what you need to be able to interpret the "payload" of the DataSet according to the schema it provides is to create an [XmlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=net-5.0) and navigate to the start of the payload element, effectively stripping off the DataSet wrapping. You want to advance the XmlReader to the root element of the payload, skipping over the associated schema, which is only description and not data. So you would want something like:

```
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream)) 
        {
            reader.ReadToDescendant("MTM");
            MTM mtmData = (MTM)serializer.Deserialize(reader);                
        }
```

Comment: I am trying this approach and using `TextReader.ReadToEnd()` to see what stream data is being given, I obviously get the whole result: schema + payload if I do that before the `using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream)` line.   If I check the result inside that using statement, I only get payload but the first 4 rows and a bit is skipped... and that is before I use `reader.ReadToDescendant()`.   Any idea why this would happen, and how I could get the payload cleanly?  When trying to deserialize  in the using statement I get the error: XmlException: Root element is missing